# trying to scrape facebook messenger chat esp. a facebook messenger group chat

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some fb messenger group chat using c# + selenium + htmlAgilitypack. Till now, i am being successful in signing in to facebook and navigating to messenger chat but I am unable to read messages in a chat and show it on my console.

```
  string webUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
        bool Loop = true;
        HtmlWeb Web = new HtmlWeb();
   Console.WriteLine("Begins");
    var options = new ChromeOptions()
        {
            BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
            AcceptInsecureCertificates = true

        };

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\anasa\OneDrive\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Web Scrapping\Web Scrapping\Classes", options);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webUrl);

        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
        element.SendKeys("email");
        element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));
        element.SendKeys("password");
        element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Log In']"));
        element.Click();
        string link = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(webUrl + "messages/t/Group.Name");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link);

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
        var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        Console.WriteLine(htmlBody.OuterHtml);
```

("//body") brings the complete body to console but when I checked messages use a class i.e "_3oh- _58nk" and upon using  doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='_3oh- _58nk']"), it shows null error.sO I  am unable to scrape messages of fb messenger.

Comment: _“I am unable to scrape messages of fb messenger.”_ - good. Because you are not supposed to do that in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
I have already extracted messages .

Answer (score 0):

Changed the statement of selecting nodes and it worked.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
        var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'_3oh- _58nk')]").ToList();

        foreach (var abc in htmlBody)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(abc.InnerText);
        }
```